# Angular - Selected option not being captured in ngForm object

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ngmodel

**Edited to remove irrelevant code.**

I am trying to print the form object to the console but the selected option is not being displayed. It is showing as *undefined* in console.

[image]

I have put the codes below. If somebody can guide on what is wrong with this particular code it would be helpful. Let me know if any additional information is required.

**Component.html:**

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(f.value)">

....

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="category">Category</label>
    <select ngModel name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.key">
        {{ c.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>

....
```

**Component.ts:**

```
import { CategoryService } from './../../category.service';

....

export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {

  categories$;

  constructor(categoryService: CategoryService) {
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();
  }

  save(product) {
    console.log(product);
  }

....
```

**Category.Service.ts:**

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

....

  getCategories() {
    return this.db
      .list('/categories', ref => ref.orderByChild('name'))
      .valueChanges();
  }

....
```

I want to get the value highlighted from the Firebase database to be captured in the object. If I put c.name I am getting the user friendly name.

[image: Firebase database structure.]

Comment: does `categories` collection has `.key` property in it?

Comment: It's a firebase database entry. I believed it has the .key property. I had tried with .$key as well.  I have updated the question to include what value I want to capture.

Comment: You should probably shorten your question a little bit. There's too much irrelevant code.

Comment: @DawidZbiński Yes, I am still getting used to posting questions. I wasn't sure where the problem was and normally I see comments from others saying that to post more code to clarify further. I erred on the side of caution and posted most of the related code here.

Comment: @DawidZbiński I have edited it as per your suggestion. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on the below link. Instead of `.valueChanges()` we should be using `.snapshotChanges()` since the former returns an Observable without any metadata.

[Upgrading to AngularFire 5.0](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md)

The updated files with the changes are given below.

**Category.service.ts:**
Changed `valueChanges()` to `snapshotChanges()`.

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

....

  getCategories() {
    return this.db
      .list('/categories', ref => ref.orderByChild('name'))
      .snapshotChanges();
  }

....
```

**Component.html:** In the select option interpolation, changed `c.name` to `c.payload.val().name`.

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(f.value)">

....

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="category">Category</label>
    <select ngModel name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
      <option value="blank"></option>
      <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.key">
        {{ c.payload.val().name }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>

....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//you need to bind object field in selection [(NgModel)] like below example


    <select [(ngModel)]="urobject.category" name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.key">
            {{ c.name }}
          </option>


     </select>
```

Comment: There is no object. This is for firebase and I am just trying to get ngForm object printed to console. I tried what you said but it didn't work.